# AWS Dynamo DB production settings with nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am looking for a tutorial that explains how to hook up a nodejs app to AWS dynamodb in production, but I cannot find any. All I could find is how to hook the app to a local test environment localhost:8000. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, please don't mention the localhost endpoint URL in the config. The SDK will automatically connect to the database endpoint based on the region provided in the config.

If you are using credentials to connect to the database, please set the credentials accordingly though it is not a recommended solution. Just to check the connectivity, you can use the credentials temporarily.

```
var creds = new AWS.Credentials('akid', 'secret', 'session');

AWS.config.update({
    region: "us-west-2",
    credentials: creds
});
```

**One of the Best Practices:-**

If you are connecting to DynamoDB from EC2, please apply the grant permission to EC2 instance. So that the database can be connected only from EC2 instance.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for